# Return everything after the first space in a javascript string

Tags: javascript

How would I return everything after the first space in a string in JavaScript? For example:

```
var myString = "This is a string.";
```

In this case, I would want to return everything after the space after "This".

```
var myOutput = "is a string.";
```

Do you know how I could accomplish this?

Comment: `"This is a string.".split(" ").splice(1).join(' ')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) to find the index of the space and use [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to pull off the part you want:

```js
var myString = "This is a string.";
let subString = myString.slice(myString.indexOf(' ') + 1)
console.log(subString)
```

You could also zap the first part away with a regular expression and [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), but it's probably less efficient and less-readable:

```js
var myString = "This is a string.";
let subs = myString.replace(/^.*?\s/, '')
console.log(subs)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this, this is a possible approach:

```js
let myString = "This is a string.";
let [_, ...myOutput] = myString.split(/\s+/);
console.log(myOutput.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using RegExp:**

```js
var myString = "This is a string.";
var myRegexp = /\w\s(.*)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: FYI, this will fail if the first character is a space.

Comment: @MarkMeyer FYI, **it wont fail**

Comment: if the string is "  is a string." starting with a space, this returns `a string.` which is *not* everything after the first space -- that's everything after the *second* space.

Comment: Well, you have to read the OP's question thoroughly then. To me it seems more reasonable to return the words after the first word and space. I could change my regex to count for the space in the beginning of the sentence but I don't think that's what the OP is after.

Comment: I'm not sure how reading the question more thoroughly makes "everything after the first space" mean something different, but it's your answer — I was just pointing out the behavior as an FYI.

Comment: And I thank you for pointing that out to my attention.
The OP says:
>return everything after the space after "This".
So returning everything after the first word and the space after it.